# The drone's rotation is sharp at the beginning of the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a proper rotation for a flying drone. I've even almost finished making it, but there is a problem that I can't solve in any way. The drone rotates too sharply at the very beginning of the game, that is, before it flies, it sharply sets the direction for about a second. I tried to set the right direction right away, hoping to correct this behavior, but it didn't help, the drone is also a sausage. During the flight, it behaves completely normally, the rotation is smooth. What could be the problem? Maybe you should use one of the lerp functions? But what context does she need then?

Drone Move method

```
    private void DroneMove()
    {
        foreach (var engine in _engines) engine.UpdateEngine(_rb, throttle);
        throttle = _throttleController.UpdateThrottle(Time.fixedDeltaTime, _rb.position.y,
            targetTransform.position.y);

        float pitch = _pitchController.UpdateThrottle(Time.fixedDeltaTime, _rb.position.x, targetTransform.position.x);
        float roll = _rollController.UpdateThrottle(Time.fixedDeltaTime, _rb.position.z, targetTransform.position.z);

        var targetPosition = targetTransform.position;
        targetPosition.y = _rb.position.y;

        _rb.AddForce(new Vector3(pitch, 0, roll) * speed);

        _finalPitch = Mathf.Lerp(_finalPitch, pitch * minMaxPitch, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);
        _finalRoll = Mathf.Lerp(_finalRoll, roll * minMaxRoll, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);
        _finalYaw = Vector3.Angle(targetPosition - _droneTransform.localPosition, _droneTransform.forward);
        
        _droneTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_finalPitch, _finalYaw, _finalRoll);
    }
```

Comment: "The drone is also a sausage" - could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dialecticus, The drone also rotates incorrectly at the very beginning

Comment: I'm also curious about the sausage sentence. Could you perhaps make a short video of the erroneous rotation? You seem to be using Euler angles for rotation instead of quaternions, so that weird snapping could be the gimbal lock.